# Placing coloured pieces on graph edges such that every cycle has at least one piece of each colour

Tags: graph-theory

Given a connected graph with N nodes, E edges, and Blue and Red pieces.

Any number (0, 1, 2, ...) of Blue and Red pieces can be placed on any edges.

1. What’s the minimum number of pieces needed to ensure that all cycles include at least one Blue piece and one Red piece?
2. Can anything be concluded about the pieces placing strategy to get minimum number of pieces?
3. Can anything be concluded about Blue-to-Red pieces ratio in the minimum pieces configuration? E.g. equal number of red and blue pieces.

Comment: This reminds me of Ramsey numbers.

Comment: I am going to assume that by "loop" you mean "cycle", because your question doesn't make sense otherwise, but let me know if I misunderstand.

Comment: Hi Misha. Thanks for your answer. Correct, cycles..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we deleted every edge with a blue piece on it, we would be left with an acyclic graph; therefore we can be left with at most $N-1$ edges. Therefore at least $E-N+1$ edges need to have a blue piece on them, and similarly at least $E-N+1$ edges need to have a red piece on them.

This lower bound can be achieved, and in general the method to do it is to:

- Pick a spanning tree $T$, and put a blue piece on every edge not in $T$.
- Pick a spanning tree $T'$ (possibly the same as $T)$, and put a red piece on every edge not in $T'$.